# Access a localStorage data inside Laravel 4.2 controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4

In my view I have this Javascript code that gets the data from a selected row from a table, puts it in a localStorage then display the data on the page.
For visualization here is what it looks like 
[image]

By default, the "Assign Grade" section is hidden and it will be only show when the user clicks the edit button on the table rows. The data from the row would then be showed on the left side of the "Assign Grade" panel. On the background what I did was when the user clicked edit I stored the Record ID inside a localstorge

My Javascript code:

```
$("#gPanel").slideDown(350);
    var index = x.rowIndex;
    var tbl   = document.getElementById("detailTable");
    var ri    = tbl.rows[index].cells[0].innerHTML;
    var sy   = tbl.rows[index].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var sq   = tbl.rows[index].cells[2].innerHTML;
    var si   = tbl.rows[index].cells[3].innerHTML;
    var sn   = tbl.rows[index].cells[4].innerHTML;


    localStorage.recid = ri;
    //more

    document.getElementById("rid").innerHTML = ri;
    //more
```

Because I need that Record ID when the "record grade" button on the "Assign Grade" panel is clicked.

Is there a way to access localStorage inside Laravel 4.2 controller? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can make an `XHR Request` in javascript to send the localStorage info to the backend.

Comment: thanks will check out ajax and xhr request :)

Comment: You need to manually pass the localStorage data to the server.